# Can i use present tense with past tense sentences?

Tags: tense-agreement

> (a) What made me sad **is** that he didn't say anything.

> (b) What made me sad **was** that he didn't say anything.

In this sentence, are both (a) and (b) possible for the main verb position?
Or is only (b) permitted ?

If both are possible, how are they different in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the past tense because "made" is in the past tense. It means you were sad *at that time*.

If you say, "What *makes* me sad..." then you need the present tense, "is". It means you are sad *now*, when you remember him saying nothing.

The tenses must 'agree'.